# Generating IDE project files

Tags: c++, c, build, ide, cmake

Here the scenario:

One creates a beautiful software library/module in C/++.

Now one wants to make it easy for new users to use this library/module.

So one wants to provide IDE project files where all the include settings, compiler flags and linker settings are set correctly.

One wants to provide project files for many different IDEs under different platforms such as: Linux (32 bit & 64 bit), Windows (32 bit & 64 bit), Mac (32 bit & 64 bit), CodeBlocks, Eclipse CDT, KDevelop3, CodeLite, Microsoft Visual Studio etc.

(Assume that all the path's to the include files and library files and all the compiler flags are known. E.g. via static paths of a downloadable SDK)

So a user that wants to use this library just has to:

- Install the library/module
- Choose the right project file (depending on the user's OS and IDE)
- Start coding
- (all include settings, compiler flags & linker settings are already correctly set in the project file)
- (no need for the user to manually set up include settings, compiler flags & linker settings)

How could one easily generate such project files from the known include settings, compiler flags and linker settings.

I have already looked at CMake (which gets very close to the final goal), but it creates an additional CMake folder to the IDE project files and also doesn't copy possible example source into the build directory.
(maybe is it possible to get CMake to generate project files without the CMake folder and with copying the source files into the build folder?)

Comment: Standard make.  Bundling project files with code is a bad idea.  Some IDEs can make use of an existing Makefile.

Comment: Google developed a tool gyp to do this for Chromium: http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypVsCMake

Comment: BTW, The preferred usage of CMake is to not have the binary folder (build output) in the source folder. I put these in a completely different tree and have a relationship such that a single source tree is used for more than 1 compiler / build tree. This way I can target 32 bit builds and 64 bit builds independently and use several different compiler versions.

Comment: There is more info here about building out of source with CMake: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F

Answer (score 3):

> (all include settings, compiler flags & linker settings are already
> correctly set in the project file)
>
> (no need for the user to manually
> set up include settings, compiler flags & linker settings)

It's possible only if your project has no dependencies. Otherwise, you can't know where deps' libs and headers are located on the user machine.

CMake have been created exactly for this - finding dependencies and generating project files.

> but it creates an additional CMake folder to the IDE project file

If you are talking about the binary dir, then it can be located anywhere, not necessary in project dir.

> and also doesn't copy possible example source into the build directory.

It's possible with `configure_file` function, or by running `${CMAKE_PROGRAM} -E copy`.